# how to change color of pen on button click in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have made a simple android program for singletouch paint, in it I have aut 4 types of pens of different sizes and I want is based on that image I want to change strokesize of pen. I have tried as below, please help me:

[image: My image screen shot]

**main.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView pen, color;
    SingleTouchView mDrawView;
    RelativeLayout layout, layout1;
    ImageView remove;
    ImageView eraser;
    LinearLayout pens;
    HorizontalScrollView myplate;
    private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
    private Button red, green, blue, cyan, yellow, orange, aqua, black, cofee,
            fuchiya, gray, indigo, khaki, lavendar, magenta, mango, maroon,
            pista, pink, purple;

    private Path mPath;

    public Canvas mCanvas;
    LinearLayout pen1, pen2, pen3, pen4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawView = (SingleTouchView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
        layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        pen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pen);
        pens = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pen1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen1);
        pen2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen2);
        pen3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen3);
        pen4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pen4);
        color = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.color);
        myplate = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myplate);

        // colors.........!!!!
        red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red);
        green = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green);
        blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue);
        orange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.orange);
        yellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow);
        cyan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cyan);
        black = (Button) findViewById(R.id.black);
        cofee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cofee);
        fuchiya = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fuchiya);
        gray = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gray);
        indigo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.indigo);
        khaki = (Button) findViewById(R.id.khaki);
        lavendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lavendar);
        magenta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.magenta);
        mango = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mango);
        maroon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.maroon);
        pista = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pista);
        pink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pink);
        purple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purple);

        red.setOnClickListener(this);
        green.setOnClickListener(this);
        blue.setOnClickListener(this);
        orange.setOnClickListener(this);
        yellow.setOnClickListener(this);
        cyan.setOnClickListener(this);
        black.setOnClickListener(this);
        cofee.setOnClickListener(this);
        fuchiya.setOnClickListener(this);
        gray.setOnClickListener(this);
        indigo.setOnClickListener(this);
        khaki.setOnClickListener(this);
        lavendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        magenta.setOnClickListener(this);
        mango.setOnClickListener(this);
        maroon.setOnClickListener(this);
        pista.setOnClickListener(this);
        pink.setOnClickListener(this);
        purple.setOnClickListener(this);

        eraser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraser);
        remove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remove);

        pen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // layout.addView(mDrawView);
                pens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        pen1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_1);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        pen2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_2);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        pen3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_3);
            }
        });

        pen4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchView.DrawingPens.PEN_4);
            }
        });

        remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layout.removeView(mDrawView);
                mDrawView = new SingleTouchView(MainActivity.this);
                layout.addView(mDrawView);
            }
        });

        eraser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mPath.reset();
                mDrawView.invalidate();
                }
        });

        color.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    // /colorpicker................!
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.black:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchView.DrawingColors.Black);
            System.out.println("==============="+SingleTouchView.DrawingColors.Black+"=========================");
            break;
        case R.id.blue:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchView.DrawingColors.Blue);
            break;
        case R.id.cofee:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.cyan:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.fuchiya:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.gray:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.green:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;
        case R.id.indigo:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.khaki:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.lavendar:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.magenta:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.mango:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.maroon:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.orange:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.pink:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.pista:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.purple:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.red:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;
        case R.id.yellow:
            myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Singleotuch.java**

```
public class SingleTouchView extends View {
    public static int width;
    public int height;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    public Paint mPaint;
    public Paint circlePaint;
    public Path circlePath;

    public enum DrawingPens {
        PEN_1(6), PEN_2(4), PEN_3(2), PEN_4(1);

        public Paint mPaint;

        private DrawingPens(final int width) {
            mPaint = new Paint();

            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);

            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        }

        Paint getPaint() {
            return mPaint;
        }
    }

    public enum DrawingColors{
        Black(Color.parseColor("#000000")),Blue(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")),Cofee(Color.parseColor("#D2691E")),Cyan(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"))
        ,Fuchiya(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF")),Gray(Color.parseColor("#808080")),Green(Color.parseColor("#00FF00")),Indigo(Color.parseColor("#4B0082")),
        Khaki(Color.parseColor("#F0E68C")),Lavendar(Color.parseColor("#E6E6FA")),Magenta(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF")),Mango(Color.parseColor("#FF8C00"))
        ,Maroon(Color.parseColor("#800000")),Orange(Color.parseColor("#FFA500")),Pink(Color.parseColor("#FFC0CB")),Pista(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32")),
        Purple(Color.parseColor("#800080")),Red(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),Tan(Color.parseColor("#0000A0")),Yellow(Color.parseColor("#FFD801"));

        public Paint mPaint;

        private DrawingColors(final int color) {
            mPaint = new Paint();

            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
            mPaint.setColor(color);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        }

        Paint getPaint() {
            return mPaint;
        }
    }

    public SingleTouchView(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public SingleTouchView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    }

    public SingleTouchView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context);
    }

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, DrawingPens>> mPaths = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, DrawingPens>>();
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, DrawingColors>> mPaths1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, DrawingColors>>();

    private Path mCurrentPath;


    private void init(final Context context) {
        setPen(DrawingPens.PEN_1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (Map.Entry<Path, DrawingPens> entry : mPaths) {
            canvas.drawPath(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getPaint());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        float eventX = me.getX();
        float eventY = me.getY();

        switch (me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mCurrentPath.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mCurrentPath.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    public void setPen(final DrawingPens pen) {

        mCurrentPath = new Path();
        mPaths.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Path, DrawingPens>(
                mCurrentPath, pen));
    }
    public void eraser() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
    }
    public void setColor(final DrawingColors color ) {

        mCurrentPath = new Path();
        mPaths1.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Path, DrawingColors>(
                mCurrentPath, color));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do You want to change stroke size of already drawn path or just of further drawing?

Comment: for further drawing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there's no ability to draw only part of `Path` using one `Paint` and draw another part with another one. So, I see the only solution - use multiple `Paths` and correspond path to the `Paint`. Also, I would suggest to encapsulate all drawing related information inside view and let Activity operate with high-level stuff.

So the following changes should be applied:

1. Use some container for `Path`s and keep Path - Paint relation inside it;
2. Provide some method from custom `View` to let Activity change current Pen;
3. Keep drawing details part inside custom view, because these details might not be needed for Activity;

Like the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    ImageView pen, color;
    SingleTouchDrawingView mDrawView;
    // Drawing view container
    ImageView mRemove;
    ImageView mEraser;
    LinearLayout pens;
    HorizontalScrollView myplate;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private View aqua;
    private ViewGroup mRootView;

    private Path mPath;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    View pen1;
    View pen2;
    View pen3;
    View pen4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mRootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
        mDrawView = (SingleTouchDrawingView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
        pen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pen);
        pens = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pen1 = findViewById(R.id.pen1);
        pen2 = findViewById(R.id.pen2);
        pen3 = findViewById(R.id.pen3);
        pen4 = findViewById(R.id.pen4);
        color = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.color);
        myplate = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myplate);

        // colors.........!!!!
        final View red = findViewById(R.id.red);
        final View green = findViewById(R.id.green);
        final View blue = findViewById(R.id.blue);
        final View orange = findViewById(R.id.orange);
        final View yellow = findViewById(R.id.yellow);
        final View cyan = findViewById(R.id.cyan);
        final View black = findViewById(R.id.black);
        final View cofee = findViewById(R.id.coffee);
        final View fuchiya = findViewById(R.id.fuchiya);
        final View gray = findViewById(R.id.gray);
        final View indigo = findViewById(R.id.indigo);
        final View khaki = findViewById(R.id.khaki);
        final View lavendar = findViewById(R.id.lavendar);
        final View magenta = findViewById(R.id.magenta);
        final View mango = findViewById(R.id.mango);
        final View maroon = findViewById(R.id.maroon);
        final View pista = findViewById(R.id.pista);
        final View pink = findViewById(R.id.pink);
        final View purple = findViewById(R.id.purple);

        red.setOnClickListener(this);
        green.setOnClickListener(this);
        blue.setOnClickListener(this);
        orange.setOnClickListener(this);
        yellow.setOnClickListener(this);
        cyan.setOnClickListener(this);
        black.setOnClickListener(this);
        cofee.setOnClickListener(this);
        fuchiya.setOnClickListener(this);
        gray.setOnClickListener(this);
        indigo.setOnClickListener(this);
        khaki.setOnClickListener(this);
        lavendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        magenta.setOnClickListener(this);
        mango.setOnClickListener(this);
        maroon.setOnClickListener(this);
        pista.setOnClickListener(this);
        pink.setOnClickListener(this);
        purple.setOnClickListener(this);

        mEraser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraser);
        mRemove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remove);

        pen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (pens.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    pens.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        pen1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingPens.PEN_1);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        pen2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingPens.PEN_2);
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        pen3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingPens.PEN_3);
            }
        });

        pen4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setPen(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingPens.PEN_4);
            }
        });

        mRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRootView.removeView(mDrawView);
                mDrawView = new SingleTouchDrawingView(MyActivity.this);
                mDrawView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.up_image);
                mRootView.addView(mDrawView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                mRootView.bringChildToFront(findViewById(R.id.tools_container));
                mRootView.bringChildToFront(findViewById(R.id.linear));
                mRootView.bringChildToFront(findViewById(R.id.myplate));
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        mEraser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBitmapPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mPath.reset();
                mDrawView.invalidate();
                pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        color.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myplate.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    myplate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pens.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // /colorpicker................!
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.black:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.BLACK);
                break;
            case R.id.blue:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.BLUE);
                break;
            case R.id.coffee:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.COFEE);
                break;
            case R.id.cyan:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.CYAN);
                break;
            case R.id.fuchiya:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.FUCHIYA);
                break;
            case R.id.gray:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.GRAY);
                break;
            case R.id.green:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.GREEN);
                break;
            case R.id.indigo:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.INDIGO);
                break;
            case R.id.khaki:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.KHAKI);
                break;
            case R.id.lavendar:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.LAVENDAR);
                break;
            case R.id.magenta:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.MAGENTA);
                break;
            case R.id.mango:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.MANGO);
                break;
            case R.id.maroon:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.MAROON);
                break;
            case R.id.orange:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.ORANGE);
                break;
            case R.id.pink:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.PINK);
                break;
            case R.id.pista:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.PISTA);
                break;
            case R.id.purple:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.PURPLE);
                break;
            case R.id.red:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.RED);
                break;
            case R.id.yellow:
                myplate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDrawView.setColor(SingleTouchDrawingView.DrawingColors.YELLOW);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And view itself:

```
public class SingleTouchDrawingView extends View {

    public int height;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;

    public enum DrawingPens {
        PEN_1(6), PEN_2(4), PEN_3(2), PEN_4(1);

        public int mWidth;

        private DrawingPens(final int width) {
            mWidth = width;
        }

        int getPenWidth() {
            return mWidth;
        }
    }

    public enum DrawingColors{
        BLACK(Color.parseColor("#000000")),   BLUE(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")),     COFEE(Color.parseColor("#D2691E")),   CYAN(Color.parseColor("#00FFFF")),
        FUCHIYA(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF")), GRAY(Color.parseColor("#808080")),     GREEN(Color.parseColor("#00FF00")),   INDIGO(Color.parseColor("#4B0082")),
        KHAKI(Color.parseColor("#F0E68C")),   LAVENDAR(Color.parseColor("#E6E6FA")), MAGENTA(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF")), MANGO(Color.parseColor("#FF8C00")),
        MAROON(Color.parseColor("#800000")),  ORANGE(Color.parseColor("#FFA500")),   PINK(Color.parseColor("#FFC0CB")),    PISTA(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32")),
        PURPLE(Color.parseColor("#800080")),  RED(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),      TAN(Color.parseColor("#0000A0")),     YELLOW(Color.parseColor("#FFD801"));

        private int mColorValue;

        private DrawingColors(final int color) {
            mColorValue = color;
        }

        int getColorValue() {
            return mColorValue;
        }
    }

    public SingleTouchDrawingView(final Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public SingleTouchDrawingView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init(context);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    public SingleTouchDrawingView(final Context context,
                                  final AttributeSet attrs,
                                  final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context);
    }

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>>> mPaths = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Map.Entry<Path, Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>>>();
    /** Stores created {@link Paint} objects */
    private HashMap<Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>, Paint> mPaints = new HashMap<Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>, Paint>();
    /** Current paint parameters - PEN_1 width and BLACK color */
    private AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors> mCurrentPaintParameters = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>(DrawingPens.PEN_1, DrawingColors.BLACK);

    private Path mCurrentPath = null;


    private void init(final Context context) {
        // Initialize default paint
        getPaintWithParameters(mCurrentPaintParameters);
        mCurrentPath = new Path();
        mPaths.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Path, Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>>(mCurrentPath, mCurrentPaintParameters));
    }

    /**
     * Helper to create Paint from parameters
     *
     * @param paintParameters
     * @return
     */
    private Paint getPaintWithParameters(final Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors> paintParameters) {
        Paint paint = mPaints.get(paintParameters);

        if (null == paint) {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(paintParameters.getKey().getPenWidth());
            paint.setColor(paintParameters.getValue().getColorValue());
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            mPaints.put(paintParameters, paint);
        }

        return paint;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (Map.Entry<Path, Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>> entry : mPaths) {
            canvas.drawPath(entry.getKey(), getPaintWithParameters((entry.getValue())));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        float eventX = me.getX();
        float eventY = me.getY();

        switch (me.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mCurrentPath.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mCurrentPath.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    public void setPen(final DrawingPens pen) {
        mCurrentPath = new Path();

        mCurrentPaintParameters = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>(pen, mCurrentPaintParameters.getValue());

        mPaths.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Path, Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>>(mCurrentPath, mCurrentPaintParameters));
    }

    public void eraser() {
        // Get default paint parameters
        mCurrentPaintParameters = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>(DrawingPens.PEN_1, DrawingColors.BLACK);
    }

    public void setColor(final DrawingColors color ) {
        mCurrentPath = new Path();

        mCurrentPaintParameters = new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>(mCurrentPaintParameters.getKey(), color);

        mPaths.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<Path, Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>>(mCurrentPath, mCurrentPaintParameters));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE (for having custom colours/widths):**

Issue with Your code was in code inconsistency and incorrect understanding of how Java `Collections` works. You don't need `mPaths1` additional collection, but should use the same collection for all drawing and maintain additional structure (in our case it's `Map.Entry<DrawingPens, DrawingColors>`) which could identify exact `Paint` and to be used with collection of paths. For more details of collections I would suggest to start at [Oracle Trials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Comment: @sandstar-thanx buddy...but how can i change color manually?your solution give me a predefined color...but wat should i do for change it manually?

Comment: @sandstar--no ,,...i am toking bout color....!how can i change it same as strokesize....manually...?

Comment: Have You seen my update? It's about color change. Hope the idea is clear. If not, let me know that exactly is not clear in update (at the end of my answer)

Comment: @sandrstar-I have used same code for color in my code ,But its not working ,Please check my updated question...dear..and i need your help for it..

Comment: Seems You need new question, because You've not been able to figure out your question initially and already updated it number of times.

Comment: @sandtar-But what is the problem if you give answer in this question??

Comment: @sandrstar please help me ..i want to change setStrokeWidth manuali..howz i possible??