# canvas drawing is not working in android

Tags: android, touch, android-canvas

i have made a simple android painting program for learning purpose,But ontouch stroke is not drawing ,i have tried as below:
**main.java**

```
package com.example.mypen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
      private Path path = new Path();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        float eventX=me.getX();
        float eventY=me.getY();

        switch (me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add path.close() in case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781069/android-null-exception-on-calling-function/17781110#17781110. check the edit part of the post might help.

Comment: @onurtaskin-not wrking............!

Comment: @Raghunandan-please give solution for my problem sir...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to invalidate your view in onTouchEvent method

Comment: oops, i didnt notice you dont use custom View, so, you just creatw custom View: class MyView extends View ...

Comment: @pskink-go to my another problem please help me for it brother..:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830799/how-to-change-stroke-size-in-android/17832686#17832686

Comment: @pskink, Is it possible draw directly using canvas object `ACTION_MOVE` without invalidate(), I just want to invalidate on `ACTION_UP`.